# Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, gzip

We use Spring Boot/MVC with annotation-based java-config for series of RESTful services and we want to selectively enable HTTP GZIP stream compression on some API responses.

I know I can do this manually in my controller and a `byte[] @ResponseBody`, however we'd prefer to rely on the Spring MVC infrastructure (filters/etc) and have it automatically do the JSON conversion and compression (i.e. the method returns a POJO).

How can I enable GZIP compression in the ResponseBody or embedded Tomcat instance, and in a way we can selectively compress only some responses?

We don't currently have any XML based configuration.

Comment: You should check out [GzipFilter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations#Gzip_Filter).

Comment: don't use HTTP compression with HTTPS unless you know what you're doing

Comment: The gzip compression is disabled by default. Check this to [enable gzip compression](https://stacktips.com/articles/enable-gzip-compression-for-spring-boot-response)

Answer (score 226):

**The rest of these answers are out of date and/or over the top complicated for something that should be simple IMO (how long has gzip been around for now? longer than Java...) From the docs:**

In application.properties **[1.3+](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression)**

```
# ️️️
server.compression.enabled=true
# opt in to content types
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
# not worth the CPU cycles at some point, probably
server.compression.min-response-size=10240
```

In application.properties **[1.2.2 - <1.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression)**

```
server.tomcat.compression=on
server.tomcat.compressableMimeTypes=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
```

**Older than 1.2.2:**

```
@Component
public class TomcatCustomizer implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(Connector connector) {
    connector.setProperty("compression", "on");
    // Add json and xml mime types, as they're not in the mimetype list by default
    connector.setProperty("compressableMimeType", "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/json,application/xml");
  }
}
```

## Also note this will ONLY work if you are running embedded tomcat:

If you plan to deploy to a non embedded tomcat you will have to enable it in server.xml http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

## IRL Production Note:

Also to avoid all of this consider using a proxy/load balancer setup in front of Tomcat with **nginx** and/or **haproxy** or similar since it will handle static assets and gzip MUCH more efficiently and easily than Java/Tomcat's threading model.

You don't want to throw 'cat in the bath because it's busy compressing stuff instead of serving up requests (or more likely spinning up threads/eating CPU/heap sitting around waiting for database IO to occur while running up your AWS bill which is why traditional Java/Tomcat might not be a good idea to begin with depending on what you are doing but I digress...)

refs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2031

Comment: Your approach for versions old than 1.2.2 won't work as Spring Boot doesn't look for `TomcatConnectorCustomizer` instances in the application context; they have to be programatically registered with `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I ended up giving up on this since it seems static/dynamic/tomcat/vs boot was still an issue. This is way harder than it should be... Nginx reverse proxy FTW!

Comment: In SpringBoot, the new properties are server.compression.enabled=true and server.compression.mime-types=XXX,YYY
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-Full-Release-Notes

Comment: I'm not using spring boot. How can I configure this in embedded jetty?

Comment: If for spring boot we have multiple rest controllers all returning JSON responses. Can we selectively apply the zip on some controllers?

Comment: Can we set this through JMX?

Comment: I have tried this but not working, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309838/spring-boot-request-response-compression

Comment: how do we verify this compression?

Comment: why no mime for js & css?

Comment: You may not need to set mime-types, because the current (Spring Boot 2) default is: "text/html", "text/xml", "text/plain","text/css", "text/javascript", "application/javascript","application/json","application/xml"

Comment: You should also mention the minimum response size for compression (ex: 10KB) otherwise it becomes overhead for the server to compress every (ex: 0.5KB) request.
`server.compression.min-response-size=10240`

Comment: This works (1.3+) with all embedded containers, not only Tomcat.

Comment: Be aware of [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) when configuring the mime-types. In particular compressing `text/html` may open you to attacks on CSRF tokens and such.

Comment: I have not been able to find an answer and might sound like stupid question but, if I enable this and communicate with another SpringBoot app, it will automatically descompress the gziped json right?

Comment: Not unless you implement IGzipAbstractFactoryResolverInterfaceDecoratorResolverProxyFacade<T, U, V> to handle it. JK. No idea :)

Answer (score 17):

On recents versions in `application.yml` config:

```
---

spring:
  profiles: dev

server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: text/html,text/css,application/javascript,application/json

---
```

Comment: The corresponding bug report and fix where this was changed is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2737

Comment: Can you use wildcard mime types? i.e `image/*`? It does not seem to work

Answer (score 13):

This is basically the same solution as @andy-wilkinson provided, but as of Spring Boot 1.0 the [customize(...)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.html#customize%28org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer%29) method has a [ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.html) parameter.

Another thing that is worth mentioning is that Tomcat only compresses content types of `text/html`, `text/xml` and `text/plain` by default. Below is an example that supports compression of `application/json` as well:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer servletContainer) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) servletContainer).addConnectorCustomizers(
                    new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                        @Override
                        public void customize(Connector connector) {
                            AbstractHttp11Protocol httpProtocol = (AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                            httpProtocol.setCompression("on");
                            httpProtocol.setCompressionMinSize(256);
                            String mimeTypes = httpProtocol.getCompressableMimeTypes();
                            String mimeTypesWithJson = mimeTypes + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                            httpProtocol.setCompressableMimeTypes(mimeTypesWithJson);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this into my Java Configuration and found that the compression didn't seem to be operating at all. I am using Spring Boot with Tomcat as the embedded container, and wondered if there were any additional things I needed to set other than this configuration?

Comment: Try verifying by specifying the `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` header, if you are using curl: `curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://url.to.your.server`

Answer (score 11):

I have added for this:

## Server compression

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=2048
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

taken from http://bisaga.com/blog/programming/web-compression-on-spring-boot-application/

Answer (score 10):

Spring Boot 1.4 Use this for Javascript HTML Json all compressions.

```
server.compression.enabled: true
server.compression.mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript
```

Comment: How do we verify this compression?

Comment: @Bhargav See the response header of your api response. It should contain the header:`Content-Encoding` : `gzip`

Answer (score 7):

Enabeling GZip in Tomcat doesn't worked in my Spring Boot Project. I used [CompressingFilter](http://pjl-comp-filter.sourceforge.net/com/planetj/servlet/filter/compression/CompressingFilter.html) found [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2014/04/01/spring-boot-configure-servlet-mapping-filters/).

```
@Bean
public Filter compressingFilter() {
    CompressingFilter compressingFilter = new CompressingFilter();
    return compressingFilter;
}
```

Comment: @user1127860 tnx this works but anyway to configure this Filter further? I use spring boot and cant seem to add init params as manual says in web.xml

Answer (score 5):

To enable GZIP compression, you need to modify the configuration of the embedded Tomcat instance. To do so, you declare a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean in your Java configuration and then register a `TomcatConnectorCustomizer` with it.

For example:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory).addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Connector connector) {
                    AbstractHttp11Protocol httpProtocol = (AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                    httpProtocol.setCompression("on");
                    httpProtocol.setCompressionMinSize(64);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

See the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) for more details on the various compression configuration options that are available.

You say that you want to selectively enable compression. Depending on your selection criteria, then the above approach may be sufficient. It enables you to control compression by the request's user-agent, the response's size, and the response's mime type.

If this doesn't meet your needs then I believe you will have to perform the compression in your controller and return a byte[] response with a gzip content-encoding header.

Comment: what is the diffrent between your answer to the option to put the setting on application.properties ? server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css

Comment: This answer was written before properties-based compression configuration was available. They are equivalent, but the properties-based approach is easier so I would recommend using that.

Comment: just want to share that in my case tomcat is behind a load balancer that get https and forword the request to tomcat as http ., when I use application.properties solution response is not gzip but when I use the programmatic config solution on connector i get gzip response with https request LB

Comment: another question in case I use application.properties solution .. and define more 2 connectors on 8081 and 8082 ports .. does compresion applay to all conectors or just to the 8080 connector ?

Comment: i verfiy this , compersion is only apply on port 8080 , even if you open more connectors .. , i think bug should be open on this to spring boot ??.. , so only work solution for me was programmatic config for each connector ,  not application.properties

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem into my Spring Boot+Spring Data project when invoking to a `@RepositoryRestResource`.

The problem is the MIME type returned; which is `application/hal+json`. Adding it to the `server.compression.mime-types` property solved this problem for me.

Hope this helps to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.pjl-comp-filter</groupId>
    <artifactId>pjl-comp-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Add following bean configuration into your configuration file.

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new CompressingFilter());
    registrationBean.setEnabled(true);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

`CompressingFilter` helps to compress the response.

You can set GZIP compression of selective endpoints using `addUrlPatterns(String)` method in `FilterRegistrationBean`.
Use `setUrlPatterns(Collection<String>)` method in case you have multiple endpoints.

If no URL pattern is set, filter compresses all responses.

Note: this won't even need to add any properties in application.properties file.