# How to enable REST gzip compression in Spring MVC without xml?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, gzip

There are some filters out there but there are no working Java only solutions or some useful libraries. I am using Spring MVC with Tomcat and deploy release to Heroku (so cannot change servlet container configuration). How to enable REST gzip compression in Spring MVC without XML?

Answer (score 4):

You could set the rule for using compression on your servlet container, for example apache-tomcat you could use the compression property. From [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html):

> **compression**
>
> The Connector may use HTTP/1.1 GZIP compression in an attempt to save
>   server bandwidth. The acceptable values for the parameter is "off"
>   (disable compression), "on" (allow compression, which causes text data
>   to be compressed), "force" (forces compression in all cases), or a
>   numerical integer value (which is equivalent to "on", but specifies
>   the minimum amount of data before the output is compressed). If the
>   content-length is not known and compression is set to "on" or more
>   aggressive, the output will also be compressed. If not specified, this
>   attribute is set to "off".
>
> Note: There is a tradeoff between using compression (saving your
>   bandwidth) and using the sendfile feature (saving your CPU cycles). If
>   the connector supports the sendfile feature, e.g. the NIO connector,
>   using sendfile will take precedence over compression. The symptoms
>   will be that static files greater that 48 Kb will be sent
>   uncompressed. You can turn off sendfile by setting useSendfile
>   attribute of the connector, as documented below, or change the
>   sendfile usage threshold in the configuration of the DefaultServlet in
>   the default conf/web.xml or in the web.xml of your web application.
>
> **compressionMinSize**
>
> If compression is set to "on" then this attribute may be used to specify the minimum amount of data before the
>   output is compressed. If not specified, this attribute is defaults to
>   "2048".

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change to Spring Boot and use an embedded Tomcat. Then you can use the `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` as suggested by [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) and myself in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful):

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer servletContainer) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) servletContainer).addConnectorCustomizers(
                    new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                        @Override
                        public void customize(Connector connector) {
                            AbstractHttp11Protocol httpProtocol = (AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                            httpProtocol.setCompression("on");
                            httpProtocol.setCompressionMinSize(256);
                            String mimeTypes = httpProtocol.getCompressableMimeTypes();
                            String mimeTypesWithJson = mimeTypes + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                            httpProtocol.setCompressableMimeTypes(mimeTypesWithJson);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

If you choose to switch to Spring Boot, there is a specific chapter about [Heroku deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#cloud-deployment-heroku) in the Spring Boot reference docs.