# How to enable GZIP for RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, gzip

I'm having a simple `REST` controller using `spring`.
How could GZIP response of the returned `application/xml` stream be enabled?

```
@RestController
public class MyRest {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ComplexRsp test() {
        //...
    }
}
```

When using soap+wsdl approach, there would be the simple `@GZIP` annotation on the service class. How can I achieve the same for REST?

Comment: careful, HTTPS + HTTP Compression can be a security hole

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Is there anywhere I can read more about that?

Comment: @FlexFiend here you go http://breachattack.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Spring boot and Tomcat You should be able to accomplish this via Tomcat Configuration: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression

Here is a similar POST [Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful)

It's as simple as follows:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/xml
```

Comment: It should be noted that this feature is NOT yet released (`1.2.2.RELEASE` will contain it).

Comment: Additionally, Spring MVC is [scheduled to add *automatic* gzip encoding handling to the `DispatcherServlet`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11714) in 4.2.

Comment: @Membersound How to do it on having WildFly ?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk-PantaRhei you should ask a separate question on this. But I'm pretty sure the `server.tomcat.*` properties can't be used here.

Comment: My Spring Boot does not use the embedded Tomcat container and I have to deploy the WAR of my application to an existing Tomcat server instance. How do I enable gzip compression in this case? Do I need to implement a gzip filter specifically?