# Understanding Gzip Compression in Spring Boot ,Angular Java Application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, compression, gzip

I am working in a Spring Boot (v 1.2) and AngularJS application. I am trying to implement GZip compression in our application to improve performance.

I want to compress my JSON response.
What i did already...

1.Enabled compression in tomcat (spring boot embedded) as below.
 References: Stackoverflow... [Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful)   and spring docs... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer servletContainer) {
            ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) servletContainer).addConnectorCustomizers(
                    new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                        @Override
                        public void customize(Connector connector) {
                            AbstractHttp11Protocol httpProtocol = (AbstractHttp11Protocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
                            httpProtocol.setCompression("on");
                            httpProtocol.setCompressionMinSize(256);
                            String mimeTypes = httpProtocol.getCompressableMimeTypes();
                            String mimeTypesWithJson = mimeTypes + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
                            httpProtocol.setCompressableMimeTypes(mimeTypesWithJson);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Now, **content-encoding:gzip is missing** in my response header.
So the above code has **no impact, as of now**.
My questions are...
1. How to set "content-encoding:gzip" in spring?
     -> I tried inside spring controller like `httpservletresponse.addHeader("content-encoding","gzip")`

But, this time, the **responsebody is empty** at the browser (after adding..`httpservletresponse.addHeader("content-encoding","gzip")`)

2. In addition to the above, **still something pending**?
   --> explicitly compress the response using java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream or  when I enable compression like `httpProtocol.setCompression("on");` this is automatically taken care by spring boot ?
   --> create a servlet filter is required?

**bottom line is** : I am not clear between the "plain servlet way of implementation" and "spring boot" way of implementation.

In Spring Boot context, Could anyone list the steps required and NOT required?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test in Spring Boot 1.2, but in Spring Boot 1.3 to enable compress for REST responces you need to enable compression in `application.properties`:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,application/javascript,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

After that all cacheable (not `POST`, `PUT`, etc) request, bigger than `server.compression.min-response-size`, will be compressed.

P.S.

In response [Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216983/1263442) exists configuration for enabling compression in Spring Boot 1.2:

```
server.tomcat.compression: on
server.tomcat.compressableMimeTypes=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```