# Huge bundle files after angular build process

Tags: angular, webpack

I've looked around online. And everyone seems to have this problem where their vendor bundle is huge. Well, my script bundle is huge. Almost 7mb. I kinda need to fix this one quickly, because that bundle takes like 27 seconds to load. 
What should I be doing to fix this? Why is it happening? Where to look for to learn more?

And also, I found documentation for webpack but did not find anything of how angular-cli builds/serves an application in conjugation with webpack.

After I run `ng build --prod`

```
chunk {0} 0.3130ddc9c1a424a149a1.chunk.js () 77.4 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.c5da564c11f7edf98974.chunk.js () 26.4 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.b84f2a93f9153e6532ca.chunk.js () 33.4 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3.d1926e2cd05a43cdc96f.chunk.js () 24.3 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4.f08daf131a3afb05cdf6.chunk.js () 16.6 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.394c153aa38c124c9f19.chunk.js () 17.3 kB {8}  [rendered]
chunk {6} polyfills.fd1491838f391af1a80a.bundle.js (polyfills) 63.1 kB {11} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {7} scripts.b2567d692113b0e5c5d5.bundle.js (scripts) 6.88 MB {11} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {8} main.b5272219b1e6fb94292d.bundle.js (main) 70.1 kB {10} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {9} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {11} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {10} vendor.e3bfc53d2baeb0d3f3f2.bundle.js (vendor) 481 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {11} inline.7c24db908bbf9f1b270a.bundle.js (inline) 1.62 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

Comment: Look at your `.angular-cli.json` The `scripts` field

Comment: For Webpack in general, this is typically caused by source maps being included in the bundle.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432673/angular2-cli-huge-vendor-bundle-how-to-improve-size-for-prod)?

Comment: Make sure you're only importing functions you're actually using. If you have something like `import "rxjs";` somewhere, for example, things start getting hairy.

Comment: @roberklep how do I remove source maps?

Comment: @yurzui yes there are quite a lot of files there. how do I go about fixing this? should I remove them from there. add them to the root folder seperately and then async load? because the first page is the login page and doesn't really require all of them to load before anything meaningful shows up. I can do that with libraries like datatable, moment etc. Is that the right way?

Comment: @srijanshukla in the Webpack configuration file (look [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool)). However, I'm not sure if `ng` uses a regular Webpack setup (no experience with it).

Comment: angular-cli disables sourcemaps by default when building with `--prod` (it implies `--sourcemaps=false`. see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build . so, if you're not using an old version, sourcemaps should not be to blame