# Angular 5 bundle size too big

Tags: webpack, angular5

I am working on building a chatbot using angular 5. I have created a small application with 8/9 components. Now the problem is production build (bundle js ) files total comes up to **3.6 MB**.
If I have to host these files on cdn it would cost a LOT.

How do I reduce the bundle size to something feasible like **100 kb** ?

Bundle details:

```
ng build
hunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 3.89 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 107 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 202 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 204 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 216 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.12 MB [initial] [rendered]

ng build --prod
chunk {inline} inline.a07175516c55c4014717.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.2e592d7ffe3a062bbdc0.bundle.js (main) 183 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.a958547e95fad8a7be8a.bundle.js (polyfills) 202 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.d93272ec54002ead254c.bundle.js (scripts) 204 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.b54edcd81812769932a0.bundle.css (styles) 197 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.343d293a3f72c924cb46.bundle.js (vendor) 2.84 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 CLI huge vendor bundle: how to improve size for prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432673/angular2-cli-huge-vendor-bundle-how-to-improve-size-for-prod)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer`.

**--[build-optimizer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--build-optimizer-and---vendor-chunk)** removes even more dead code than **--prod** but it needs **--aot** flag to work, which means [Ahead of Time Compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

You could also, [get Typescript Hero Plugin](https://github.com/buehler/typescript-hero/wiki) that will organize and remove unused imports.

Check the whole project looking for unused components, models, classes, services. Deleting them will reduce your final bundle size. Hope this helps.

Comment: --aot and --build-optimizer are both enabled by default when we build for production in angular-cli now, therefore there is no more need to use them explicitly.

Comment: So, do you suggest to use just "--prod" flag?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with large prod bundles and fixed the issue with this command;

```
npm run build
```

I had been using

```
npm run ng build --prod
```

but the --prod flag seem to be ignored if you use 'ng'

See my full answer on another thread
[How to reduce vendor/script bundle.js in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641811/how-to-reduce-vendor-script-bundle-js-in-angular-5/50800451#50800451)

Comment: If the same answer works for different questions, then we consider those questions to be duplicates.  Instead of answering again, please flag the question as a duplicate.