# How to reduce vendor/script bundle.js in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have already used `ng build -prod -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimize` to reduce the size of the builded app.
Now this is my situation:

[image: Builded app]

Is it possible to reduce (or maybe split) these bigger chunks?
Is there something that can help me to inspect inside these modules?

P.s. I have already used [webpack-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to inspect the situation but it can't go deep into these files.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles

Answer (score 5):

Build your app with sourcemaps, then use a tool like [`source-map-explorer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) that details the size of every part of library that you're using.

Some tips with common libraries :

- If you're using RxJS 5.5 or higher, use the `.pipe(operator1(), operator2())` syntax, it significantly reduces RxJS size when you don't use many different operators
- If you're using moment.js be sure to import only the locales you're using
- If you're using Angular Material, be sure you don't import unused modules
- If you're using bootstrap and SASS, import only the needed parts of `.scss` files

If you didn't already do it, divide your app into lazy modules, it will reduce the size of the initial chunk.

Comment: I have this error if I use sourcemap: `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: I've never had this error when building an Angular app... There is a discussion about it here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618. It looks like there are working solutions

Comment: @Alessandro try to limit memory with `node --max_old_space_size=3072 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng ...`

Comment: @MartinChoraine pretty sure he has already found something, 2 months later ;)

Comment: dayjs is a nice drop-in replacement for momentjs!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with large prod bundles and fixed the issue with this command;

```
npm run build
```

I had been using

`npm run ng build --prod`

but the --prod flag doesn't execute and I was left with a vendor.bundle.js which was 2.9mbs

```
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 3.89 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 349 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 16.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.96 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

With just npm run build (no ng) the whole dist folder is 400kb

```
chunk {0} polyfills.67d5a7eec41ba0d20dc4.bundle.js (polyfills) 101 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.3874ea54d23e70290fa8.bundle.js (main) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.0aad5eda327b47b9e9fa.bundle.css (styles) 1.56 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry For Late Reply.
This answer will work for all newer versions of Angular.

1. If you are using Angular Material, Then import from the specific package exporter.

Ex:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

istead of

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
```

2. Avoid using Common Material Module throughout your application.

If you are using LazyLoading module, Import required packages in the specific module.

I followed these steps, I got reduced bundle size from 9.0MB to 1.45MB.

Hope it will work for you guys also :).