# Minimize vendor.bundje.js in Angular

Tags: angular, docker, angular5, angular6, gitlab-ci

I made an Angular 5 application and when I run `ng serve` and tries to open it in browser, it take 20-30 seconds to open because `vendor.bundle.js` is 48MB.

Is there any way to minimize it while using compression or another option?

**p.s. I can't use `ng build` because I am using Docker and Gitlab CI/CD so the only possible way to make it run is by `ng serve` i guess.**

Comment: using `ng build` should package the whole app smaller as it builds it for use rather than dev testing

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes but as I said, I need to use Gitlab CI/CD and Docker, and what I've seen so far the only way to make it run on Docker with Gitlab CI/CD is with `ng serve`

Comment: ng serve never keeps the compiled files, they are temporary, so unless docker can build angular apps, yiu need to use ng build

Comment: @mast3rd3mon so it means that the only way to minimize is to use `ng build` right?

Comment: there are probably other ways but you should be building your application anyway

Comment: @mast3rd3mon ok then thank you. I'll try to find a way to run it on Docker using `ng build`

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to use `ng build` instead of `ng serve`, you need it at all costs.

After that, if your vendor file is still big, take a look at tools like `source-map-explorer` as described in [How to reduce vendor/script bundle.js in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641811/how-to-reduce-vendor-script-bundle-js-in-angular-5) and consider adding gzip compression to your HTTP server (likely Apache or Nginx)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use `ng build` which it converts at around 8MB