# vendor.bundle.js goes heavy in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a project on angular 5.2.6., but problem is that when I load the application, it takes almost 20-30 seconds.

When I check in the network tab in the browser, I saw that vendor file is taking time because of is size(11.6 Mb).

I want to know that is there any way to minimize that vendor file and what kind of code are packed inside vendor file. I got [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4059) link but not get the solution.

How can I minimize that vendor file to load my application faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 CLI huge vendor bundle: how to improve size for prod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432673/angular2-cli-huge-vendor-bundle-how-to-improve-size-for-prod)

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Brk's answer, there are multiple things you can do ontop of that to minimise the load time of your vendor.bundle.js or other files :

1. Minification using UglifyJs : It removes all the white spaces and comments. Estimated size reduction is 40-50%.
2. Configuring your Server to send your JS/Html or any files by automatically compressing them in gzip format. Browser automatically unpacks it and uses your Js files as intended.

If you do these 2 your load time would decrease by 80%.

I did the same , my vendor.bundle.js went from 8 MB to 600 KB.

**UGLIFYJS** :

uglifyjs  dist/vendor.bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output  dist/vendor.bundle.js

*Note* : You can download uglifyjs using npm

Comment: Thank you @Aakash Uniyal but please also tell me that how to configure UglifyJs in angular2/4

Comment: so i just need to install that uglifyjs using npm or any thing more @Aakash Uniyal

Comment: You probably won't need anything else

Comment: thank you @ Aakash Uniyal i am trying. i will let you know the response shortly

Comment: @ Aakash Uniyali i have done it. but it is not doing any thing.

Comment: vendor.bundle.js file size got decreased ?

Comment: no @ Aakash Uniyal it is still in his same size(11.6). i think i have to do some imports after running npm command

Comment: are you running the given command from the root of your angular app ?

Comment: yes after login from the root i go to my project directory and then i run npm install uglify-js command

Comment: This command : uglifyjs dist/vendor.bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/vendor.bundle.js

Comment: now it is giving error `ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dist/vendor.bundle.js'
`

Comment: and when i remove dist folder form command then yet it gives error `ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dist/vendor.bundle.js'
`

Comment: actually i already run command to run my application for forever. then i am running command for uglifyjs.

Comment: please help me next what should i do.

Comment: when i run `ng build -prod -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimizer` then it shows size of vendor.bundle.js is 472 kb but when i run in browser it again show it 11.6 mb