# Angular 5 - Main bundle file is too large on the development server

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, aot

We are developing an application using `Angular 5`. After running the `ng build --prod --aot` and deployed the dist folder to the dev server the main bundle produced `2.2MB on initial load`. It's already small compared to `8MB` vendor bundle size (when running ng build --prod) but still, we need to lower the size of the main bundle. Is there any way to lower the size of the main bundle?

[image: network]

Comment: You can exclude node_modules folder from bundle.

Comment: Can you provide `index.html` and `.angular-cli.json` files?

Comment: Hi @ManojChalode

Please see this [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/BN8gRUoeVQcaAnfbLAUr/) to see index.html and .angular-cli.json

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the bundle size by adding build-optimizer flag to your build:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Try running the above command. For more info visit: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

AFAIK you need not have to include `--aot` flag when building using `--prod`. **Production** build is aot by default.

Updating to the latest version of angular is also a solution for this. Since latest version often comes with more optimized build procedures.

Comment: Hi Gautam, I tried to ran the command but the size main bundle still 2.3 MB

Comment: Hi @Eugene then try using the steps provided in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358855/4214976

Comment: Tried this command "ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer=true --vendor-chunk=true" and it lowered the size from 2.3MB to 869KB. However it created a vendor file with the size of 1.7MB which I think still the same

Comment: --aot and --build-optimizer are suprlus when using --prod

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to separate your code into modules and load them lazily.