# Angular main.js file large size

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-ui-router, angular-builder

My project user angular version 7, and here is the angular.json configuration [image]

when I build for production my main.js file is way too large nearly 12MB in size which makes my app to load the page very slowly. Nearly the initial load tooks 4 - 5 minutes

Here is the build result
[image]

Here is my analyser result
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try taking a look at the Webpack Bundle Analyzer: https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack

Comment: While this is understandably frustrating, there doesn't seem to be a direct programming question asked here. It also seems like the nature of the issue might need more than a simple reproduction to debug. As @Pace said, analyzing the bundle is a good place to start.

Comment: What is the command you used to build it?

Comment: ng build --prod, where I didn't added any other since all the default things are already there in the angular.json configuration, as you see the picture above @wentjun

Comment: @TheLawliet94 got it. Hmm.. And what is the total size after compressing? You know you can deliver compressed files via your servers, right?

Comment: I tried that and I updated my my analysed result above @Pace

Comment: No I haven't tried that @wentjun

Comment: If you expand the menu on the left there is an option to show concatenated contents.  It claims to be inaccurate but it should give you a rough idea.

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue @TheLawliet94 ?

Comment: Yeah, with proper lazy loading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the file which is taking too much into modules and apply lazy loading

Comment: My build contains main.js file which size is 12MB, will applying lazy loading solve this large file size issue. @Prashanthi

Comment: Divide your large modules (app.modules) into multiple sub modules with max size per sub module should be less than 3 MB and then apply lazy loading to these modules.You will see a drastic increase in the performance.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I've already lazy loading things. I have app module and 5 other modules. I don't know where exactly am making mistake.

Comment: And when you look at the image above,  I don't know why it is showing main.ts + 357 modules (concatenated)

Comment: This answer tells us in only one sentence **what** to do but not **how**.

Answer (score 6):

- First of all, stop using  webpack bundle analyzer because it does not
  give accurate representation of your bundle space and start using
  [source-map-explorer](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer#readme).
- As per the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility), if you import any thing outside of lazy loaded module, **then it will be included in your main.js bundle**. I had this issue where I was importing shared module in every module and shared module itself imported a lot of packages from `node_modules` which led to an increase in main.js file.

Comment: Here are the steps I followed:
1. Identified the js included in my main bundle
2. I had already implemented lazy loading of modules, but figured few other components can be included in their lazy loaded modules as well
3.  I started breaking one big shared module into smaller commonly used components shared module and added them in the lazy loaded modules imports

Comment: How do you lazy load a shared module? Because it wont have routing.

Answer (score 1):

if you was try lazyload module and it still not work.
change the `tsconfig.json` module from `commonjs` to `es2020` and add `sideEffects: false` to your `package.json` and then, voila:

[image]

full explain I was talk in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342681/5748537

btw, you can use `g-zip` on server to make it faster.