# Barrel file and Tree Shaking

Tags: webpack, import, tree-shaking

*Here is an example repository that shows an example of the issue reported in this thread: https://github.com/Eux86/tree-shaking-barrel-test/blob/master/README.md*

I'm trying to understand what's the effect of using a Barrel file to export functions and classes from a library project when importing it into another project that use webpack and should be able to treeshake the bundle.

Imagine I have a project:

library

- index.ts
- libA.ts
- libB.ts

index.ts has this code:

```
export { LibAMain } from 'LibA';
export { LibBMain } from 'LibB';
```

So I'm using index as a barrel file to export all the functions I'm going to develop in my library.

The second project will be:

library-user

- index.ts

Index.ts has this code:

```
import { LibAMain } from 'library'

LibAMain();
```

Now: library-user is builded using webpack, which I expect to be able to treeshake the unused libraries in MyLib, but when I look into the generated bundle I see that it contains both LibA.js and LibB.js, which shouldn't be there:

[image]

If I change index.ts to:

```
import { LibAMain } from 'library/lib/LibA'

LibAMain();
```

then webpack does its job well and I only see LibA in the final bundle:

[image]

TL;DR: How can I keep using the barrel index file and just import everything from 'library' but still have the treeshaking working?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Possibly the same issue I'm experiencing here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74442696/webpack-doesnt-split-a-huge-vendor-file-when-modules-are-exported-and-imported

Answer (score 21):

It looks like a module problem in your code, not webpack.
tsconfig.json

```
...
"module": "commonjs",
...
```

Commonjs modules system [doesn't support](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion) tree shaking in webpack (only direct imports like you did it above works `mylib/libA`).
To fix tree shaking in your github repo you should use `module`: `es2015` or `esnext` in `tsconfig.json`.

```
...
"module": "esnext",
...
```

But you are right - unfortunetely treeshaking is not webpack's best side.
There are several approaches how to shake your tree better:

1. [Plugin to improve treeshaking](https://github.com/vincentdchan/webpack-deep-scope-analysis-plugin)
2. [Side effects](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free) webpack option
3. [Used exports](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationusedexports) webpack option
4. Move from `webpack` to `rollup`. Rollup has first-class tree shaking by default (I don't recommend to do it for large projects).

Comment: Why you don't recommend Rollup for large projects?

Answer (score 5):

By looking for an answer to my own question [Webpack doesn't split a huge vendor bundle when using barrel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74442696/webpack-doesnt-split-a-huge-vendor-bundle-when-using-barrel-files) I've found a solution that should apply in this case as well.

Basically you can continue to use **barrel files**, but you need to disable **side effects** from those specific files (the **barrel files**).

I've tried this solution in two separate projects with different versions of **Webpack** (**4** and **5**) and it works on both.

This is the relevant part of the configuration:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules...
      {
        test: [/src\/common\/index.ts/i, /src\/hooks\/index.ts/i],
        sideEffects: false,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the GitHub issue where I've found the explanation: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557.

Comment: More details in this article: https://renatopozzi.me/articles/your-nextjs-bundle-will-thank-you