# What is the impact of importing from TypeScript barrel index files on Webpack v4 code-spliting / tree-shaking?

Tags: typescript, webpack, circular-dependency, code-splitting, tree-shaking

I am using TypeScript barrel index files (i.e. re-export pattern) to solve a needed cyclic dependency (i.e. circular imports) as explained [in this article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de).

However, the article's author mentioned that this could impact code-splitting / tree-shaking by bundlers such as Webpack v4. I just want to understand the impact in general and how does it manifests itself?

Is there a better way to do solve circular dependencies and maintain better code-splitting / tree-shaking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Barrel file and Tree Shaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527907/barrel-file-and-tree-shaking)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your barrel files, but you need to disable side effects, otherwise Webpack will import all the exported files every time you need a single module.

I discovered it while investigating on my own question: [Webpack doesn't split a huge vendor file when modules are exported and imported using index files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74442696/webpack-doesnt-split-a-huge-vendor-file-when-modules-are-exported-and-imported/) where you can maybe find more details.

Here is the Webpack configuration to disable side effects from specific files:

```js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules...
      {
        test: [/src\/common\/index.ts/i, /src\/hooks\/index.ts/i],
        sideEffects: false,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```