# I am trying to create react component library and bundling the same with webpack to target esm but my component lib is not treeshakable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, components, es6-modules

"`Usage of my lib in a project`

```
import {Button, Input} from "my-lib"
```

if i am using analyze or source-map-explorer in the project to check the build details, build file shows complete lib is included in the final build instead of only adding the button and input component

sharing config of my-lib

webpack config

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { join, resolve } = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
// const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");

const getPackageJson = function (...args) {
    const packageJSON = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(join(__dirname, "./package.json"))
    );
    if (!args.length) {
        return packageJSON;
    }
    return args.reduce((out, key) => {
        out[key] = packageJSON[key];
        return out;
    }, {});
};

const {
    name: pkgName,
    version,
    description,
    license,
    author,
    homepage,
} = getPackageJson(
    "name",
    "version",
    "description",
    "license",
    "author",
    "homepage"
);

const banner = ` Name: ${pkgName}
 Version: ${version}
 Description: ${description}
 Author: ${author}
 Homepage: ${homepage}

 Copyright (c) ${author.replace(/ *<[^)]*> */g, " ")} and project contributors.

 This source code is licensed under the ${license} license found in the LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.`;

// common
const common = {
    mode: "production",
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    externals: ["react"],
    resolve: {
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".css", ".scss"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
            },
            {
                // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{ loader: "ts-loader" }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin(banner),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                // parallel: true, // Multi-threading
                extractComments: false,
            }),
        ],
    },
};


module.exports = [
    {
        output: {
            path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "[name].common.js",
            library: {
                type: "commonjs",
            },
        },
        ...common,
    },
    {
        output: {
            path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "[name].umd.js",
            libraryTarget: "umd",
        },
        ...common,
    },
    {
        experiments: {
            outputModule: true,
        },
        output: {
            path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "[name].esm.js",
            library: { type: "module" },
            environment: { module: true },
            // sourceType: module,
        },
        ...common,
    },
    {
        output: {
            path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "[name].min.js",
        },
        ...common,
    },
];
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "loose": true,
                "modules": false,
                "targets": {
                    "esmodules": true
                },
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": { "version": 3, "proposals": true }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        [
            "@babel/preset-typescript",
            {
                "isTSX": true,
                "allExtensions": true
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components",
            {
                "ssr": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["ES2017", "ES7", "ES6", "DOM"],
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./build/",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "importHelpers": true,
        // "noEmit": false,
        // "allowJs": true,
        // "skipLibCheck": true,
        // "noImplicitThis": false,
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

        "paths": {
            "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "@providers/*": ["src/providers/*"],
            "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
            "@src/*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "noErrorTruncation": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "examples/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "**/*.spec.tsx", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

package.json

```
"type": "module",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/main.esm.js",
    "unpkg": "dist/main.min.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "sideEffects": false,
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "src",
        "tsconfig.json"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "bundle": "webpack --config webpack.lib.config.js",
    },
```

If we are consuming only 2 components of my-lib in a project, then final build of my project should have only those 2 components instead of complete my-lib package

Comment: You should probably turn off side effects in the Webpack configuration, try to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527907/barrel-file-and-tree-shaking/

Comment: Why are you even bundling your lib instead of just compiling and publishing for cjs and esm consumers?