# Spring boot request response compression

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman

I have a spring boot app which produces a json response which is huge, its almost 2MB. I have tried solutions available online by trying to add the following in application.properties file but it didn't work, can someone help?

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
```

This is the method signature if it helps,
I am using spring boot version 1.3.3 and testing the service with postman.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getAssetsSMC",method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String getAssetsSMC(@RequestParam(value = "accessKey", required = true) String accessKey) throws IOException
{
  // code 
return gson.toJson(products);
}
```

Comment: Do you use an embedded server or building a war and deploying it. Which Spring Boot version are you using. How are you testing the compression?

Comment: I am using the embedded tomcat, only building jar. using spring boot version 1.3.3 and testing compression via Postman