# GZIP compresion in my spring boot web app

Tags: java, spring, .htaccess, maven, gzip

I'm trying to compress my web app with GZIP and I am using **.htaccess** file to do so!

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

I have placed it in the same directory with my **index.html**

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it since it does not work! 
so please can someone tell me how to do it I'm using spring boot maven app 
and I've to say I'm still a beginner and I really need your help 
thank u all for your help 
much respect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful)