# JSON Response compression in Spring 4.2

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I have a web application build on Spring 4.2.5 and hibernate. We have some api's in that application and response is in JSON. Size of response json is almost around 6mb for which we need to compress the response so that size can be reduced and performance can be improved. Need help in implementing compression mechanism in Spring.
**Note**: We are not using spring boot. Application is on Spring 4.2.5

Comment: I think it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991007/compress-and-send-large-string-as-spring-http-response/48001798#48001798

Comment: m looking to compress the json returned from the response body in Spring mvc restcontroller.

Comment: so you will be doing it in UI?

Comment: No Mobile api will consume.