# gzip compression of API response in Grails 3

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gzip, grails-3.0

I want to compress my API responses above a certain threshold. I'm using Grails 3.0.11 and since Grails uses spring boot underneath it, I used Spring configurations to enable response compression. I used following configuration snippet in my `application.yml`:

```
server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
        min-response-size: 2048
```

This should work as mentioned in many tutorials for spring boot, but it isn't working for me because when I hit any API with response size greater than 2048 bytes, I don't get `content-encoding=gzip` response header. What am I doing wrong?

I used these configurations from here: http://bisaga.com/blog/programming/web-compression-on-spring-boot-application/

I'm testing my APIs using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). That can be a culprit too.

## Update

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful), I got the idea of the difference between configurations for different spring-boot versions. My current spring-boot version is 1.2.7. So I tried to use following configurations too but to no avail:

```
server:
    compression:
        enabled: on
        compressableMimeTypes: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
        min-response-size: 2048
```

Comment: Is there anything else in between your postman and your service?  Like another proxy that may not be allowing that header through?

Comment: Nope. I'm using it directly from embedded tomcat. And it is mentioned in the documentation that these configurations work with embedded tomcat.