# How to enable GZIP compression in Spring MVC with annotation on a controller class/method

Tags: spring-mvc, gzip

I'm researching migration from JAX-RS to Spring MVC and I stuck with GZIP.

In Apache CXF (one of JAX-RS implementation) it's possible to use @GZIP annotation at controller level that indicates that all resources in this class will be gzipped. From [documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/common/gzip/GZIPFeature.html):

> This class is used to control GZIP compression of messages. Attaching
>   this feature to an endpoint will allow the endpoint to handle
>   compressed requests, and will cause outgoing responses to be
>   compressed if the client indicates (via the Accept-Encoding header)
>   that it can handle them.

I can't find how to do the same easily in Spring MVC. gzip is not mentioned in official documentation and answers like [Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful) show solutions for Spring Boot (not Spring MVC) that are application-wide (should be only for certain controllers).

Is there a simple solution for Spring MVC to enable GZIP compression by using annotation on a controller class/method. (maybe via custom message converter?)

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this ?