# I want to change "Transfer_encoding:Chunked" to "Transfer-Encoding:gzip,deflate" in response headers of SOAP service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, soap, java-ee-6

I am new in j2EE and developed an inbound SOAP service which fulfill all requirements but my client ask me to change Transfer-Encoding type to "gzip,deflate" which is by default set to "chunked".
I do not know what actually Transfer-Encoding is, how it is set by-default and how can i change its value by using java spring.
Kindly elaborate these terms in simple words too.

I am attaching screenshot of SoapUI software through which i requesting my inbound service and gets response.
Kindly ask me for more details if required.
Thanks in advance and sorry for using poor english.

[SoapUI screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMpDz.jpg)

Comment: There's a question covering how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful

Implementation depends on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work for my case. I am using tomcat 8.5.4.

Comment: What have you tried? There are several different methods of turning on gzip compression. That's what you need to lookup.

Comment: i added properties in my application.properties file. i tried all of them