# Gzip on Spring server or Nginx (reverse proxy)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx

Pretty straight forward question:

What are the pros/cons for enabling gzip on Spring server v.s. nginx? The Spring Server is only used to serve RESTful api requests (json) and Nginx is used as a reverse proxy before the Spring server

I searched around but no one seems have a very good answer. This answer ([Using GZIP compression with Spring Boot/MVC/JavaConfig with RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410317/using-gzip-compression-with-spring-boot-mvc-javaconfig-with-restful)) talks about it should be enabled on nginx because it's more efficient (and IRL people do this)

Thus I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this? What people usually do?

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance: Dont use Nginx for that!

Nginx gzip process is a content filter, this is not compatible with `send_file` optimisation (more details at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#enabling-sendfile):

> Enabling the sendfile directive eliminates the step of copying the data into the buffer and enables direct copying data from one file descriptor to another.

As such, I would recommend to use a HTTP proxy for that, (you could use another Nginx! What I am doing all the time), and setup `proxy_cache`:

Nginx -- (proxy cache) --> Nginx -- gzip --> CSS/JS files

Answer (score 1):

Most people would recommend enabling it on *nginx*. The thinking is to free *Spring* from as much work as possible since:

- *Spring* uses considerably more memory per request and connection than *nginx*.
- *Spring* might hold on to a database connection while it's processing a request. And database connections on the database server are expensive too.
- *Spring* is more difficult and more expensive to scale up than *nginx* if the load requires so.

For most setups, the difference will be small and not noticeable. I have never measured it in practice. Other people might have more experience.