# SpringBoot gzip compression of json data, does the decompression works automatically?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gzip

Im seeing some alternatives to reducing the size of my json data here:

[baeldung guide](https://www.baeldung.com/json-reduce-data-size#gzip)

Im interested in the gzip option, but I was wondering if the decompression is also automatically? For example in my case it is going to be sending this data to another SpringBoot application, will it be able to read it automatically and get the json to then get the object? Havent done this before so there is my question... Also I am using Jetty in both applications, not Tomcat, does this affect? I ask because here they mention that it [must be Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216983/12085680)

Also if you know another way to do it without the way they show in the Baeldung guide feel free to point it out :)